# How to split a multi-valued, character delimited column into multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Long time lurker, first time question asker...

I haven't found an answer to this specific problem though it seems familiar I'm sure.

I have a table with a column containing a semi-colon delimited list of values.  The table is a list of applications along with the servers associated with that application.  The list of servers is semi-colon delimited but is separated into serverId;serverName for x number of servers - there are some applications associated with hundreds of servers, some are associated with 1, and some are associated with 0.  I would like to separate this servers column into rows for each unique server including the Id from the table as well as the serverId and serverName as columns.

Data currently looks like this

`applicationId\Servers
    1\serverId1;serverName1
    2\serverId2;serverName2;serverId3;serverName3
    3\serverId1;serverName1;serverId5;serverName5;serverId8;serverName8
    4\serverId9;serverName9
    5\`

I'd like to create a new table with the applicationId, serverId, and serverName columns, like this:

`applicationId\serverId\serverName
    1\serverId1\serverName1
    2\serverId2\serverName2
    2\serverId3\serverName3
    3\serverId1\serverName1
    3\serverId5\serverName5
    3\serverId8\serverName8
    4\serverId9\serverName9
    5\`

Alternatively, if I could just get the serverId into a table with the the applicationId it would be helpful as I do have a table with serverId and serverName, as well.

`applicationId\serverId`

I have tried splitting the column on just ';' but that produces not very helpful output like the following:

`applicationId\serverColumn
    1\serverId1
    1\serverName1
    2\serverId2
    2\serverName2
    2\serverId3
    2\serverName3
    ....`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The biggest issue here is that you are storing delimited data. Now you want to move from one delimited version to another. This is not a good plan. You should consider moving this to a normalized design instead.

Comment: Your problem is that you have stored a `one to many` relation into just one table. Fix that by normalizing your data and not only this problem, but all future problems about this will go away

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only way I can consume the data otherwise I would definitely not design it this way.

Comment: can you elaborate why this is the only way ?

Comment: The data is ingested from a SharePoint list via SharePoint List Source and Destination [link](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652).  There is an application list in sharepoint, each application is associated with a list of servers upon which it is dependent.  This just seems to be how the data comes in from that SSIS data flow task.

Comment: So when the data gets inserted/updated from your SSIS you have a change to split it there and insert/update it into normalized tables. It still seems possible to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an awful data structure to say the least. But it is possible using Jeff Moden's splitter. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ I know you say you have a splitter but if it has a loop or recursive cte you need to throw it away for a set based one like Jeff's.

Here is a fully functional example of how you could leverage his splitter to make this work.

```
declare @Something table 
(
    ApplicationID int
    , ServerInfo varchar(100))
insert @Something 
(
    ApplicationID
    , ServerInfo
) values
(1, 'serverId1;serverName1')
, (2, 'serverId2;serverName2;serverId3;serverName3')
, (3, 'serverId1;serverName1;serverId5;serverName5;serverId8;serverName8')
, (4, 'serverId9;serverName9')
;

with ServerIDs as
(
    select s.ApplicationID
        , ServerID = case when x.ItemNumber % 2 = 1 then x.Item end
        , x.ItemNumber
    from @Something s
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(s.ServerInfo, ';') x
    where x.ItemNumber % 2 = 1
)
, ServerNames as
(
    select s.ApplicationID
        , ServerName = case when x.ItemNumber % 2 = 0 then x.Item end
        , x.ItemNumber
    from @Something s
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(s.ServerInfo, ';') x
    where x.ItemNumber % 2 = 0
)

select si.ApplicationID
    , si.ServerID
    , sn.ServerName
from ServerIDs si
join ServerNames sn on sn.ApplicationID = si.ApplicationID and si.ItemNumber + 1 = sn.ItemNumber
```

This returns:

```
ApplicationID   ServerID    ServerName
1               serverId1   serverName1
2               serverId2   serverName2
2               serverId3   serverName3
3               serverId1   serverName1
3               serverId5   serverName5
3               serverId8   serverName8
4               serverId9   serverName9
```

Comment: This did the trick!  Thank you!  I hadn't thought of using modulus operation to get this working but it makes total sense and works great.

Comment: Glad that helped. But seriously....try to figure out a better approach than storing delimited data.